# Amazon S3 cp command can't bring the deleted file on a version enabled S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 Amazon S3 buckets A and B. Version enabled on both the bucket.

There is file X present on bucket A and B bucket is empty. Now I ran

```
aws s3 sync s3://A "s3://B"
```

The above command copied file X from bucket A to bucket B. Then I delete file X from bucket A.

I ran this command again but this time copying from B to A

```
aws s3 sync s3://B "s3://A"
```

In log I can file is getting copied from bucket B to Bucket A but when I checked bucket A, I don't see file X. Only when I click show version I can see the file marked as `Delete marker`.

How I can make file X available on bucket A. I tried `cp` command as well.

Comment: have you tried following this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/RemDelMarker.html

Comment: When you run the second `sync` command, it normally prints to the screen which objects were copied. I suspect you'll find that the object is _not_ copied from B to A because it "already exists" (or at least it did in a previous version). Or, I might be wrong. Does it show as a copied file?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes I did show copying when I use CP command

Comment: Please edit your question to show the commands you are using and the output displayed, so that we can attempt to recreate your situation.